# Convert Git Repo to TFS team collection

Tags: github, tfs

I need to migrate Git Repository to  TFS and migrate means not import into TFS git but it also needs to be converted in TFS Team collection along with the history so further we can utilize it as TFVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can migrate all history of main branch from local repo to a new TFVC team project with following steps:

1. Create an empty TFVC team project
2. Go to your local Repo folder, and use `git-tf checkin --deep` command to checkin the local repo to a TFVC team project. By default, the checkin command will create a single TFS changeset for the aggregate of all changes made on the current branch in Git since the last checkin to TFS. When used with the **--deep** option, a TFS changeset will be created for each Git commit on the current branch since the last checkin to TFS.

[image]

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately it does not migrate history

Comment: Do you have commits in your git repo? Do you add --deep option? I have double confirmed that with --deep option, the history in git repo will be migrate to TFVC project.

Comment: @ChetanWaghmare, could you double checked this solution?

Comment: The image link is dead (and would benefit from being shown inline or having a link description once fixed).