# Convert Git repo to team project on VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is it possible with Visual Studio Team Services using Git to convert a repository under a team project to its own project *with full history*? So, here's the as-is structure in the VSTS:

- MyTeamProject1

  - MyRepo1
  - MyRepo2
- MyTeamProject2

Here's the desired structure:

- MyTeamProject1
- MyRepo1 (could be renamed to a Team Project)
- MyRepo2
- MyTeamProject2

In other words `MyRepo1` and `MyRepo2` Git repositories are now team projects in VSTS and their history is preserved.

I've seen this solution but it's talking about creating a collection, not a team project, and not sure if it keeps the commit history during the migration: [Convert Git Repo to TFS team collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019296/convert-git-repo-to-tfs-team-collection)

During the migration, I don't want to move away from Git to TFVC; wish to continue using Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Team Project is a *container* for things like work items, source code repositories, build definitions, etc.

Thus, what you want to do is:

1. Create a **new team project**
2. Add an empty repository to it
3. Add a *remote* to your existing repository (on your workstation)
4. Push that repo to the empty repo created in step #2.

However, it's worth noting that general guidance is to [keep everything within a single team project](http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, @DanielMann. Reading through the article now. Might stay with currect single team project design

Comment: Impossible to say in general terms. It depends on a lot of different factors.